# How to prepend Image after if-else check of div position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

There is a Key image on my site which when clicked moves to the left. After that I want a car to appear alongside the key immediately. Below is the jQuery code pasted.

After below code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#key").click(function(){
        $("#key").animate({left: '-1000px'},"slow");
        $("#key").animate({width: '16%'},"slow");
        $("#key").animate({top: '190px'},"slow");
        $("#key").css({transform: 'rotate(-90deg)'},"slow");

    });
});
```

I want below to be executed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var n = $("#key").position();    
    if (n.top=="190px" && n.width=="16%" && n.left=="-1000px") {        
        $(".car").prepend('<img id="car" src="assets/car_fin.png" />');
    }
});
```

Comment: you can minify your code with $("#key").animate({left: '-1000px', width: '16%', top: '190px'},"slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  })

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: No. Now even the key is not moving.

Comment: I have updated the answer with code snippet and it works now, I guess there was a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use animate complete function to prepend your second image like following.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#key").click(function(){
        $("#key").animate({left: '-1000px', width: '16%', top: '190px'},"slow", function() { 
           // Animation complete.                      
           $(".car").prepend('<img id="car" src="http://via.placeholder.com/180x180" />');
        });
        $("#key").css({transform: 'rotate(-90deg)'},"slow");

    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-lnH4vnCtlKU2LmD0ZW1dU7ohTTKrcKP50WA9fa350cE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>     
<img id="key" style="position:relative;margin-left:200px;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x140">
<div class="car">
  car image
</div>
```

Comment: Now the key is not moving also.

Comment: @prk_passion01 I have updated my answer with code snippet and it works now, I guess there was a syntax error.

Comment: @prk_passion01 your welcome :) please consider to accept (tick) the answer to help people understand problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for that if statement cause you can simply use your code inside you your if statement as a callback for the animate when it completes.